# SqlAlchemy / Python Datatypes

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am struggling to get my python and sql  datatype speaking to each other. I'm not sure what I am missing here.

My Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String, Float, DATE, DECIMAL

def db_conn():
    global conn
    global engine

    db_uri = "sqlite:///db.sqlite"
    engine = create_engine(db_uri)

    conn = engine.connect()
    meta_db = MetaData(engine)

    print("Connected to Database at: " + str(datetime.today()))

    return conn

db_conn()

# create table
meta = MetaData(engine)
table = Table('MarketData2', meta,
   Column('DT', Integer, primary_key=True),
              Column('Currency', String),
              Column('Signal', String),
              Column('Value', Float))
meta.create_all()

def update_MarketData_db(dt, currency, sig, val):
    # insert multiple data
    conn.execute(table.insert(),[
       {'DT': str(dt),
        'Currency': str(currency),
        'Signal': str(sig),
        'Value': float(val)}])

update_MarketData_db('2014-05-04', 'test', 'test_blac', 420.0)
```

As you can see, I explicitly declare each datatype in the function. Also I have tried the Float, FLOAT, Decimal and DECIMAL classes in sqlalchemy and that hasnt worked either.

The traceback:

```
IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) datatype mismatch [SQL: 'INSERT INTO "MarketData2" ("DT", "Currency", "Signal", "Value") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: ('2014-05-04', 'test', 'test_blac', 420.0)] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)
```

Comment: Isn't the issue on the `"DT"` column which you've defined to be an `Integer`, yet you're passing in a `string`?

Comment: Also conn.execute looks strange when it takes function as 1st parameter and one-element `list` containing `dict` as 2nd parameter

Comment: I think the problem is that `Column('DT', Integer, primary_key=True)` receives a value like `'2014-05-04'` which is definitely not integer.